# IE 8 Invalid Argument Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I am getting this error in IE 8,

***Invalid argument. jquery.min.js, line 4 character 25149***

its been three days i am not able to figure out the problem. Its working fine in every browser except IE8

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        var icons = {
            header: "iconClosed",
            activeHeader: "iconOpen"
        };
        $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content",
            icons: icons,
            animate: {
                duration: 1000
            }
        });
        $('#tabs').tabs();
        $('.ui-corners-all, .ui-corners-top').removeClass('ui-corners-all ui-corners-top');
        $(".selector").accordion({
            clearStyle: true
        });
        $('#nav li ul').slideDown();
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
        $('#nav li a').addClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

    });
    jqb_init();
    clearInterval(jqb_intInterval);
    checkbox_click();
});
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using ? Can you confirm you're not using the 2.x branch ?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in unminified mode?

Comment: Look at the call stack to find the lines that belong to _your_ code.

Comment: I am using jQuery v1.7.2

Comment: You're calling document.ready inside a document.ready callback and you try to do `$(window).next()`.

Comment: I am not so good in  Javascript any idea how to solve this

Comment: Read the documentation of jquery's ready function. For the rest, your goal isn't clear.

Comment: i am getting "Invalid Argument" while i debug it in VS 2010 on this "a.elem.style&&a.elem.style[a.prop]!=null?a.elem.style[a.prop]=a.now+a.unit:a.elem[a.prop]=a.now}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

I just included JavaScript 1.9.1 Used in accordion demo on official accordion page.

Yet this doesn't solve my problem entirely. This cause "Object Expected Error".

Which I am Familiar too. "Object Expected Error" means Script could not be found.

AS including JavaScript 1.9.1 Overriding my own script which was in Master page.

So I move it from Master Page to My Page.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your code, remove evident and unnecessary code:

```
$(function() {
    var icons = {
        header: "iconClosed",
        activeHeader: "iconOpen"
    };

    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        icons: icons,
        animate: {
            duration: 1000
        }
    });

    $('#tabs').tabs();

    $('.ui-corners-all, .ui-corners-top').removeClass('ui-corners-all ui-corners-top');

    $(".selector").accordion({
        clearStyle: true
    });

    $('#nav li ul').slideDown();
    //this is window: window->next->slideToggle? For what? Is it necessary?
    //$(this).next().slideToggle();
    $('#nav li a').addClass('active');
    //this is window: window->addCssClass? Like link? For what? Is it necessary?
    //$(this).addClass('active');
    jqb_init();
    clearInterval(jqb_intInterval);
    checkbox_click();

});
```

Comment: Set code back in comments. Please, answer why is it necessary? What are you try to do by this code?

Comment: i have a sub menu nav which i am opening and making selected page value highlight